# ASP.NET MVC applications missing controller folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I just got responsibility of managing two ASP.NET MVC applications hosted on IIS. I have no previous experience with ASP.NET (C#), and very minimal knowledge of any ASP.NET MVC application. Mostly Python backend development.

When I'm reading the documents on Microsoft website, the application should have model, view, and controller. However, I don't see controller folder for two of the application I inherited. When I review the code on GitHub posted by the previous team, the controller folder and controller file are there. I'm not sure if there is a technique to place the controller file somewhere or disappear during the build process.

The application is currently running, and these are the only directory available in IIS. Where is the controller folder?

[IIS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybpTD.png)

Comment: when you say *I don't see controller folder* are you looking for this folder from visual studio solution explorer or windows explorer? if you find it from the windows folder then you can include them manually after show all files from the solution explorer menu options,.

Comment: can seem stupid but checks that you are in the right branch of the git project or that your pull request is right done.

Comment: The web application is currently running on IIS. The controller folder doesn't show on here.

Comment: Is "here" in your visual studio solution or in file explorer in the project folder? Not that is probably is the case, but controllers don't have to be in folders named controllers (but they almost always are).

Comment: @mason: this is the correct answer, post it. The compiled version of the app doesn't contain C# sources but in a typical deployment scenario CSHTML files are there. People that come from python or node.js can possibly find it unusual to not to see source code in the deployment location.

Comment: @mason, Thanks. I'm so used to not compiling the code for the web app, I didn't realize compiling is required for this.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks, yea looks like I do need to go through some documentation and training for this.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't looking at the source code. You're looking at the compiled and published application. Of course there won't be a controller or models folder there: they've been compiled into DLL's. You need to look at the source code. You mentioned you see them in GitHub: you need to clone that GitHub repo and then you'll have what you need. From there, you'll need to figure out how they deploy the app to IIS (or come up with your own way of deploying).